# How can i create a new column that inserts cells from other columns, but in a pattern of 3 from first column, then 3 from second column, and on...?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So In this exmple I have 3 columns with 9 cells each.
(Its only an example, in real life it may be 100 columns with 1000 cells each).

Columns:

- Apples
- Bananas
- Grapes

I want to create a 4th column that has the first 3 cells from apples, then 3 cells from bananas, then 3 cells from Grapes, then 3 cells from Apples again, and on...

[image]

So I tried giving the cells a secuence, and then dragging the secuence downwords hoping excel would get the pattern I was looking for. Then I thought of copying all 3 columns in one column and ordering the secuence from most small to most big, but Excel dosent get my pattern.

Do you guys know any other possible solution? Or how can I get Excel to get my pattern when dragging down?

Comment: You can use the `INDEX()` function in combination with `MOD()`, `INT()` and `SEQUENCE()` to refer to the rows and columns in a certain pattern. If no one else provides a complete solution in the meantime, I can elaborate tomorrow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=LET(a,A3:A11,
     d,D3:ED11,
     h,H3:H11,
     shift,3,
     join,HSTACK(a,d,h),
     rw,ROWS(join),
     col,COLUMNS(join),
     sq,SEQUENCE(rw*col,,0),
INDEX(join,      
      (MOD(sq,shift)+1)+shift*INT(sq/(col*shift)), 
      MOD(INT(SEQUENCE(rw*col,,shift)/shift)-1,col)+1))
```

It stacks the ranges and indexes it. The sequences reference the correct rows/columns.

If you add a range the formula will still work, as long as you add it to `join`

The first (row) sequence (`(MOD(sq,shift)+1)+shift*INT(sq/(col*shift))`) uses the sequence of the rows*columns wrapped in MOD with the number of rows you want to use as a shift as a divisor to create a counter of 1,2,3,1,2,3,etc.
This would keep referencing the first three rows, but after we reached the third row of every column, we need to shift to the next sequence of rows. `shift*INT(sq/(col*shift)` is used for that; the integer of the total sequence divided by the number of columns times the shift creates a counter starting at 0 adding 1 every 9 rows.
So the counter of 1,2,3,1,2,3,etc will add the number of columns times 0 (3*0 = 0) for the first nine rows; then 3*1 = 3 for the next nine rows, etc.

The second (column) sequence `MOD(INT(SEQUENCE(rw*col,,shift)/shift)-1,col)+1)` calculates the integer of the sequence of the rows*columns (+ number of rows shift) divided by the number of rows shift (-1). This results a repeat of numbers adding 1 every three rows, starting at 0; so 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,etc. up to the number of rows -1 is reached.
Wrapping that in MOD with the number of columns as a divisor results in the same counter (this time starting at 1), but everytime the counter exceeds the number of columns it resets to 1; so 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,etc.

[image]

Comment: Can you give a more step to step explication on the second part? 
From Index and on, Ive been studying your formula, but cant get that part.

Comment: I tried to do ur formula manually.
1. First I did the Join Part.
2. Then in the index(Join, Rows, Columns) for each sequence I got as results only 1s for the rows, and only 1s for the columns, so the index result was always Apple1.

Comment: Explained it further and showed it in a picture to visualize.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the total number of rows of the input is divisible by `3`, then you can try in cell `H2` (*Formula 1*):

```
=DROP(REDUCE("", SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A10)/3,,0,3), LAMBDA(ac,cnt, LET(ss, 
  SEQUENCE(3)+cnt, VSTACK(ac, CHOOSEROWS(A2:B10,ss), CHOOSEROWS(C2:D10,ss), 
  CHOOSEROWS(E2:F10,ss))))),1)
```

If you don't want to generate the `Seq` columns in the output, then adjust the range in `CHOOSEROWS`. Under this scenario, since you are returning one column, you can replace `CHOOSEROWS` with `INDEX`.

By the way, if the sequence data is part of the input to consider, then the solution is more straightforward:

```
=SORTBY(VSTACK(A2:A10, C2:C10,E2:E10), VSTACK(B2:B10, D2:D10, F2:F10))
```

or the sequence column values can be generated as follow (`byArr`) and produces the same output as previous formula:

```
=LET(n,3,m,ROWS(A2:A10),seq, WRAPCOLS(SEQUENCE(n*m),n), byArr, DROP(REDUCE("",
  SEQUENCE(m/n,,0,n), LAMBDA(ac,it,VSTACK(ac,CHOOSECOLS(seq,SEQUENCE(n)+it)))),
  1), SORTBY(VSTACK(A2:A10, C2:C10, E2:E10), TOCOL(byArr,,TRUE)))
```

Here is the output of *Formula 1*:
[image: sample output file]

### Explanation (*Formula 1*)

We use `REDUCE` to concatenate the `VSTACK` output per iteration. The number of iterations is defined by `ROWS(A2:A10)/3` and the rows to select on each iteration via `CHOOSEROWS` is determined by: `SEQUENCE(3)+cnt`.

The array (where each element in `REDUCE` is represented by `cnt`):

```
SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A10)/3,,0,3)
```

represents the offset we apply on every iteration: `0,3,6,...`.

`DROP` is used to remove the first row, because we don't have a good value to initialize the accumulator (`ac`). You can initialize it with the header, in case you want to generate it, then `DROP` function is not required. For example replace `REDUCE(""` with: `REDUCE({"Cells", "Ordered Sequence"}`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with INDEX(database,row,col):INDEX(database,,row,col)
could be this formula.

=LET(n_cells,3,database,B2:D10,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(database)/n_cells),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TOCOL(INDEX(database,y * n_cells-(n_cells-1),):INDEX(database,y*n_cells,),,TRUE)))),1))

[image: How can i create a new column that inserts cells from other columns, but in a pattern of 3 from first column, then 3 from second column, and on...?]